# javascript - how do i add a textbox to a 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would i add a text box as an input to a 2d array? I have the textboxes as a form. What is the simplest way to assign each student input to a seat? 
Edit: would i need to put a document.getElementById(seat1).innerhtml into the function?

```
<form id="studentForm">
<input type="text" name="student1" id="myInput1">
<input type="text" name="student2" id="myInput2">
<input type="text" name="student3" id="myInput3"><br>
<input type="text" name="student4" id="myInput4">
<input type="text" name="student5" id="myInput5">
<input type="text" name="student6" id="myInput6"><br>
<input type="text" name="student7" id="myInput7">
<input type="text" name="student8" id="myInput8">
<input type="text" name="student9" id="myInput9"><br>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {

var seat = onearray(3)
seat[1] = onearray(3)
seat[1][1]
seat[1][2]
seat[1][3]

seat[2] = onearray(3)
seat[2][1]
seat[2][2]
seat[2][3]

seat[3] = onearray(3)
seat[3][1]
seat[3][2]
seat[3][3] 
}

</script>

<label for="Seat1">Seat 1 </label>

<p id="seat1"></p>

<label for="Seat2">Seat 2 </label>

<p id="seat2"></p>

<label for="Seat3">Seat 3 </label>

<p id="seat3"></p>

<br>
<label for="Seat4">Seat 4 </label>

<p id="seat4"></p>

<label for="Seat5">Seat 5 </label>

<p id="seat5"></p>

<label for="Seat6">Seat 6 </label>

<p id="seat6"></p>

<br>

<label for="Seat7">Seat 7 </label>

<p id="seat7"></p>

<label for="Seat8">Seat 8 </label>

<p id="seat8"></p>

<label for="Seat9">Seat 9 </label>

<p id="seat9"></p>
```

Comment: Do you want to the computer automatically organize the seats and students, or you want to the students choose the seat by they self, which they want to reserve?

Comment: i want it to be like a teacher making the seating plan and being able to set the seats for each student also i am going to need to put something in this stuff that i left out

Answer (score 0):

Try to use document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]") to get the array with all inputs of type "text". You need to iterate through them.

```js
/* Select all the inputs wich have the type as a text, this will return an array */
var students = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
/* Create an empty multidimensional array, for the seats*/
var seats=[[],[]];
/* Initailize student counter to 0*/
var studentCounter=0;
/* Iterate the seats, most of the time the seats are character + number like: B-24 (file B seat 24), but this time in order to simplify the script I lef as a number like 2-24  (file 2 seat 24) */
// 24 files x 10 seats for each file = 240 available seats 
    for (var i =0; i <= 24; i++) {
      for (var x=0; x < 10; x++) {
        //Here we capture the input box content, example name of the student
        if(students[studentCounter]){
          seats[i][x]=students[studentCounter].value;
          studentCounter++;
        }
        
      }
 
    }
  console.log(seats)
```

```html
<form id="studentForm">
<input type="text" name="student1" id="myInput1" value="Jon Doe1">
<input type="text" name="student2" id="myInput2" value="Jon Doe2">
<input type="text" name="student3" id="myInput3" value="Jon Doe3"><br>
<input type="text" name="student4" id="myInput4" value="Jon Doe4">
<input type="text" name="student5" id="myInput5" value="Jon Doe5">
<input type="text" name="student6" id="myInput6" value="Jon Doe6"><br>
<input type="text" name="student7" id="myInput7" value="Jon Doe7">
<input type="text" name="student8" id="myInput8" value="Jon Doe8">
<input type="text" name="student9" id="myInput9" value="Jon Doe9"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: So would the var code be inside the function then or?

Comment: I have modified the script to add the students to a seat, for 24 rows and 10 columns

Comment: im new to coding do you think you could explain what you did indepth?

Comment: I have added comments to the script, how do you will get the students list? this will be came from a service like jSon?

Comment: This is just a practice code with no use. its just so that you can put the code in have it in an array and be able to see it in the same order

Answer (score 0):

This is what i did in the end

```
<html>
<head>

      <title>Two Dimensional Arrays D</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">

      function Input()
                 {
                 var seat = new Array()

                            seat[0] = new Array();
                             seat[0][0] = Form1.txtInput1.value;
                               seat[0][1] = Form1.txtInput2.value;
                                 seat[0][2] = Form1.txtInput3.value;

                           seat[1] = new Array();
                                    seat[1][0] = Form1.txtInput4.value;
                              seat[1][1] = Form1.txtInput5.value;
                                seat[1][2] = Form1.txtInput6.value;

                          seat[2] = new Array();
                                   seat[2][0] = Form1.txtInput7.value;
                             seat[2][1] = Form1.txtInput8.value;
                               seat[2][2] = Form1.txtInput9.value;

                  txtLabel1.value = seat[0][0]
                   txtLabel2.value = seat[0][1]
                    txtLabel3.value = seat[0][2]
             txtLabel4.value = seat[1][0]
              txtLabel5.value = seat[1][1]
               txtLabel6.value = seat[1][2]
                txtLabel7.value = seat[2][0]
                 txtLabel8.value = seat[2][1]
                  txtLabel9.value = seat[2][2]

                   }
</script>

</head>
<form name="Form1">

        <table name="InputTable">
          <tr>
                       <td>
                            Name: <input type="text" name="txtInput1"  id="txtInput1">
                    </td>

                        <td>
                             Name: <input type="text" name="txtInput2" id="txtInput2">
                     </td>

                 <td>
                              Name: <input type="text" name="txtInput3" id="txtInput3">
                      </td>
          </tr>

              <tr>
                   <td>
                                Name: <input type="text" name="txtInput4" id="txtInput4">  
                    </td>

                <td>
                     Name: <input type="text" name="txtInput5" id="txtInput5">
             </td>

                 <td>
                      Name: <input type="text" name="txtInput6" id="txtInput6">
              </td>
          </tr>

      <tr>
                   <td>
                        Name: <input type="text" name="txtInput7" id="txtInput7">
                </td>

                    <td>
                         Name: <input type="text" name="txtInput8" id="txtInput8">
                 </td>

             <td>
                          Name: <input type="text" name="txtInput9" id="txtInput9">
                  </td>
      </tr>
  </table>

    <input type="button" onClick="Input()" value="Submit" name="btnSubmit">

   <br />
        <br />

    <table name="OutputTable">
      <tr>
                   <td>
                        Seat 1: <input type="text" name="txtLabel1" id="txtLabel1">
                </td>

                    <td>
                         Seat 2: <input type="text" name="txtLabel2" id="txtLabel2">
                 </td>

             <td>
                          Seat 3: <input type="text" name="txtLabel3" id="txtLabel3">
                  </td>
      </tr>

          <tr>
               <td>
                            Seat 4: <input type="text" name="txtLabel4" id="txtLabel4">
                    </td>

                <td>
                     Seat 5: <input type="text" name="txtLabel5" id="txtLabel5">
             </td>

                 <td>
                      Seat 6: <input type="text" name="txtLabel6" id="txtLabel6">
              </td>
          </tr>

      <tr>
                   <td>
                        Seat 7: <input type="text" name="txtLabel7" id="txtLabel7">
                </td>

                    <td>
                         Seat 8: <input type="text" name="txtLabel8" id="txtLabel8">
                 </td>

             <td>
                          Seat 9: <input type="text" name="txtLabel9" id="txtLabel9">
                  </td>
          </tr>
      </table>

   <br />
        <br />
            </form>
            </body>
            </html>
```